# Bitwise XOR between uint8 and logical in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 8x1 uint8 vector that I want to bitwise XOR with a 8x8 logical matrix, so I need to xor 64 bits with 64 bits in different formats. The result must be a 8x8 logical matrix.

The reason for this is that I am working with a .bmp image and a binary image.
How do I do this in Matlab R2012a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xor(de2bi(double(A)),B)
```

If you don't have de2bi.m (Communications Toolbox), take the de2bi.m from an octave installation (open source) and replace "endfunction" with "end" and "endif" with "end" or use this definition: `de2bi=@(x)dec2bin(x)=='1'`.